# Preventing Persistent CSS Styles Across Pages in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm using SvelteKit and have encountered an issue where CSS styles persist across page changes. I'm importing a CSS file in a Svelte component like this:

```
<script>
    import "$lib/styles/sample.css";
</script>
```

The problem occurs when navigating between pages: the styles from sample.css remain applied even after moving to a page where sample.css is not imported. However, if I reload a page where sample.css was not imported, the styles from sample.css disappear, as expected.

This behavior suggests that once a CSS file is loaded, its styles persist across page changes within the SvelteKit app, affecting pages that haven't explicitly imported the CSS file.

I'm looking for a solution to either:

Automatically remove the CSS styles applied from sample.css when navigating away from a page that imported it.
Ensure that the CSS styles from sample.css do not affect pages that have not imported it.
Any advice or solutions to prevent CSS styles from persisting across pages in a SvelteKit application would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a method to dynamically load a CSS file for specific pages in a SvelteKit application and then remove it when navigating away. This solution leverages Svelte's `onMount` and `onDestroy` lifecycle functions. The CSS file I used for this example is stored at `/static/css/sample.css`. Below is the implementation:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount, onDestroy } from "svelte";

    let link;
    let cssPath = "/css/sample.css";

    const appendCss = (filePath: string): HTMLLinkElement => {
        const link = document.createElement("link");
        link.type = "text/css";
        link.rel = "stylesheet";
        link.href = filePath;
        document.head.appendChild(link);
        return link;
    };

    onMount(() => {
        link = appendCss(cssPath);
    });

    onDestroy(() => {
        link.remove();
    });
</script>
```

This technique is particularly useful for managing styles that should only be applied to certain pages within a SvelteKit application, avoiding any unintended style persistence across different pages.

### Postscript

I've found an easier and more direct way to include CSS on specific pages in my SvelteKit application. All I had to do was load the CSS in `<svelte:head>`.

Here's a simplified method:

```
<svelte:head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/sample.css" />
</svelte:head>
```

I hope this is useful for anyone looking for an easier way to manage CSS in SvelteKit.